# Returning variable from callback into a defined function-NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
music.playsong = function(vars){
//vars is an array with a Key named "song"
youTube.search(vars["song"], 2, function(error, result) {
  if (error) {
   console.log(error)

   return;
  }else {
     console.log("Success")
    return result
 }
 })
}
```

I am currently calling this function as

```
music.playsong(data)
```

However in this function I can not access the underlying callback and get the value from that. How do I get this ***music.playsong()*** to return the result of the callback without blocking execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want use a async function as sync. So it's not possible. So you need to change your method to be async like this :

```
music.playsong = function(vars, cb){
//vars is an array with a Key named "song"
youTube.search(vars["song"], 2, function(error, result) {
  if (error) {
   console.log(error)

   process.nextTick(() => {
    cb(error)
   })
  }else {
     console.log("Success")
     process.nextTick(() => {
      cb(null, result)
     })
 }
 })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
music.playsong = function(vars){

youTube.search(vars["song"], 2, function(error, result) {
if (error) {
   return callback("Error",{});
}else {
    console.log("Success")
    return callback(""success",result)
    }
})
}
function callback(data){
//TODO
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that `youtube.search` is an asynchronous action.

In this case, you should use `Promise`

e.g.

```
music.playsong = function(vars) {
  return Promise(resolve, reject) {
    //vars is an array with a Key named "song"

    youTube.search(vars["song"], 2, function(error, result) {
      if (error) {
        return reject(err);
      } 
        console.log("Success")
        return resolve(result);
      }
    })  
  }
}

music.playsong('').then(function(result) {
  // you will get result here
});
```

In Promise, you will have `resolve` and `reject` for handling async action.

when `resolve` got called, it will pass `data` to `.then`
when `reject` got caleed, it will pass `err` to `.catch`